Book set in a dystopian United States where a young boy or teen travels to military bases
For reference, I'm 18 now, but I must have read it in either 4th or 5th grade, or possibly 6th, so 2016-2018. I just recently started thinking of this book I read, as the plot was amazing to me personally, but I can't remember the name.
Mostly what I can remember is that it's set in a post-apocalyptic United States where the country has kind of fallen apart and there're only military bases around, I believe. There's this young boy (I also think he might have a younger brother, but not solid on that choice), and he has to travel around to these bases for some reason and do something with them.
I understand the plot I remember is vague, but any help is appreciated, thanks!

This could sort of fit Ender's Game but that's probably not it.
